# Monitor button press

Tags: android

I would like to know when the send message button is tapped. Is this possible using android accessibility? In my code I can find out if the button is visible, but I don't know how to monitor the tapping. My idea is to get the last text from the TextView always after I detect the tap on the send button.

[image]

```
package com.system.wifi.service;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;

import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;

import com.system.wifi.model.MessageSent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> textViewNodes;
    MessageSent messageSent;

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d("TAG", "onServiceConnected................................................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onAccessibilityEvent..............................................");

        textViewNodes = new ArrayList<AccessibilityNodeInfo>();


        if(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED == event.getEventType()){
            Log.e("TAG", "TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED.....................................");    
            
            List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> messageNodeList = getRootInActiveWindow().findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.gbwhatsapp:id/send");

            if (messageNodeList == null || messageNodeList.isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }

            AccessibilityNodeInfo sendMessageButton = messageNodeList.get(0);

            if(sendMessageButton.isVisibleToUser()){
                Log.d("TAG", "button is visible");
            }


            AccessibilityNodeInfo rootNode = getRootInActiveWindow();
            if (rootNode == null) {                    
                return;
            }

            findChildViews(rootNode);    
            
            for (AccessibilityNodeInfo mNode : textViewNodes) {
                if (mNode.getText() == null) {
                    return;
                }

                Log.d("TAG", mNode.getText().toString());
            }

            rootNode.recycle();
        }


    }


    private AccessibilityNodeInfo findChildViews(AccessibilityNodeInfo parentView) {

        if (parentView == null || parentView.getClassName() == null) {
            return parentView;
        }

        int childCount = parentView.getChildCount();

        if (childCount == 0 && (parentView.getClassName().toString().contentEquals("android.widget.TextView"))) {    
            
            textViewNodes.add(parentView);

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                findChildViews(parentView.getChild(i));
            }
        }
        return parentView;
    }



    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("TAG", "onInterrupt.......................................................");
    }
}
```